# I want to clear textbox if date is invalid, it is working fine for tab but not working for Enter button suggest something to do with this code

Tags: javascript

<asp:TextBox ID="txtmutdate" OnTextChanged="txtmutdate_TextChanged" autocomplete="off" onblur="validatedate(this)"  AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"  Height="28px" Font-Size="8pt" Width="90%" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>

Javascript Function:

function validatedate(input) {

```
        var date_regex = /^((0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(19|20)\d{2}$/;
        if (!(date_regex.test(input.value))) {
            input.value = '';
        }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the pressed key on `keyup` event, if it's `enter` then validate date.
try this:

```
 $("#<%=txtmutdate.ClientID%>").keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        validatedate(this);
    }
});
```

Comment: function checkEnter(event) {
            if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                var date_regex = /^((0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(19|20)\d{2}$/;
                if (!(date_regex.test(event.target.value))) {
                    event.target.value = '';
                }
            }
        }

Comment: onkeydown="checkEnter(event)"

Comment: basically the idea is same except you're using a different event (keydown).